# Use the name of the original file for the output file

Tags: powershell

I have been able to get this script working but the only thing I cant figure out is to take the original file name and apply it to the output file name with _new added to it. Could you please push me in the write direction?

```
Import-Csv '\\DESKTOP-QC1GB24\Allpay DD\Processing\*.csv' -Header (1..5|%{"Column$_"}) |
    Select-Object Column2,Column3,Column5 -SkipLast 1 |
    ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
    Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
    Set-Content -Path "\\DESKTOP-QC1GB24\Allpay DD\Completed\New.CSV"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of .csv files before the import and loop through them:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.csv' -Path '\\DESKTOP-QC1GB24\Allpay DD\Processing\'|
  % {Import-Csv $_.Fullname -Header (1..5|%{"Column$_"}) |
      Select-Object Column2,Column3,Column5 -SkipLast 1 |
      ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
      Select-Object -Skip 1 | 
      Set-Content -Path "\\DESKTOP-QC1GB24\Allpay DD\Completed\$($_.BaseName)_new.CSV"}
```

This way `$_.Fullname` points to each Full Path of an file and `$_.BaseName` gives you the Name of each file without the extension (in this case .csv). This way you can add the `"_new"` string during the `Set-Content`.

Comment: Perfect, just as i wanted, I couldnt have been further away from what you did.Thanks so much for answering that for me.